# Updating DataTable

Tags: c#, system.data.datatable

```
for(int i = 0; i < m_DataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    m_DataTable.Rows[i]["WORKER"] = "test";
    m_DataTable.Rows[i].AcceptChanges();
}

m_DataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Is there any reason that I can not see that this code does not update my dataTable?

Comment: It seems OK to me... (perhaps Row.AcceptChanges is even useless since you call AcceptChanges on the whole DataTable at the end). How do you notice that the datatable is not updated ? Do you inspect it through debug-watch, or is it bound to a DataGridView ?

Comment: The code is fine. If you are using DataGridView (as digEmAll assumed) then you need to refresh it after Datatable was updated - Datagridview.Refresh().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't you be creating a data adaptor and call `Update` to update the dataset changes to your database, *before* you call `AcceptChanges`?

Something like:

```
using (DataAdaptor adaptor = new DataAdaptor("SELECT * FROM table", connection)) {
    using (CommandBuilder builder = new CommandBuilder(adaptor)) {
        adaptor.Update(m_DataTable);
    }
}

m_DataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Correct... DataTable by itself is for "in memory" content displayed to the user and not that committed to actual disk. The DataAdapter allows the synchronization from local in-memory table to the server which it is connected to. (intended for @mariusgherman)

Comment: I wasn t trying to update the database itself, just thought that could be the cause. Anyway you helped solve the problem after all. ty